# Current lockdown situations in Thailand and Korea?

Tags: covid-19, thailand, south-korea

I'm planning a trip with a friend and we're thinking of going to either Thailand (Chiang Mai) or Korea (Seoul and/or Jeju).  We want to go to local places, meet and hang out with local people, go to bars, restaurants, etc, and don't want to deal with covid or lockdown related issues, e.g. business closures, reduced hours, (if possible) vaccination pass (we are both vaccinated but it's still annoying to deal with), etc.

Does anyone know what the current status of covid-related closures or other measures in these 2 locales are (as of today, August 22 2022)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of August 2022:

In **Thailand**, COVID is effectively "over". If you are vaccinated, there are no special entry procedures, and once in the country there are no COVID-related restrictions, QR check-ins, etc. Masks are no longer mandatory anywhere, although they're still recommended and quite common especially in Bangkok, but much less so in the beach resorts. I would imagine Chiang Mai would be somewhere in between.

**Korea** remains more strict: you are required to take a professionally administered pre-departure ART/PCR, *and* another one on arrival. I haven't been to the country since they reopened, so I can't speak from personal experience, but I gather masks remain mandatory in most indoor settings.  Most businesses are open normally and QR check-ins are only required for high-risk environments like nightclubs.

So, if minimizing COVID hassle is your sole criterion, Thailand is the clear winner here.

Comment: I'd note that Thailand went as far as to acknowledge COVID as a routine seasonal disease: https://planetofhotels.com/guide/en/blog/thailand-declared-covid-19-reclassified-seasonal-disease

Comment: As for Bangkok, AFAIK they're still officially required on public transit.

Comment: @JonathanReez That's company policy, not law: https://www.lifestyleasia.com/bk/travel/destinations/thailand-mask-mandate-has-been-lifted/

Comment: That's true but unlike the much more lax mask policies in the West, I presume this one is actually enforced.